# Invoke non-default constructor for class array member

Tags: c++, constructor

I have an array in my class called `items`. When creating object of type `MyClass`, I need to invoke parameterized constructor `Member(int value)`. How to do that?

```
class Member
{
public:
    Member();
    Member(int value)
    {
        dummy = value * 2;
    }
    ~Member();

private:
    int dummy;
}

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass();
    ~MyClass();

private:
    Member items[10];
}
```

UPDATE:
I am now debbugging more simple case with single element, not an array. Maybe you see more: why this work

```
user_menu_view::user_menu_view() :
    button_clicked_callback(this, &user_menu_view::button_clicked),
    on_touch_button_item_selected(this, &user_menu_view::touch_button_item_selected),
    users_items(menu_item_common::BACKG_LONG)
{
    users_items.set_back_color((uint16_t)0x1951);
    users_items.set_menu_item_selected_callback(on_touch_button_item_selected);
    meniu_list.add(users_items);
}
```

And this doesn't:

```
user_menu_view::user_menu_view() :
    button_clicked_callback(this, &user_menu_view::button_clicked),
    on_touch_button_item_selected(this, &user_menu_view::touch_button_item_selected)//,
    //users_items(menu_item_common::BACKG_LONG)
{
    users_items = menu_item_touch_button::menu_item_touch_button(menu_item_common::BACKG_LONG);
// Also, here destructor routine is called. WHy???
    users_items.set_back_color((uint16_t)0x1951);
    users_items.set_menu_item_selected_callback(on_touch_button_item_selected);
    meniu_list.add(users_items);
}
```

Comment: Just use a vector or map. Or a loop that assigns values.

Comment: You wrote: "// Also, here destructor routine is called. WHy???" Becouse when you do object = another_object; - the destructor of object is called like this: object->~ClasName() and than copy-constructor called like this: object(another_object). So you need to carefully implement destructor and copy-constructor for all complicated objects (i have write this in my answer).

Comment: Shouldn't destructor, as you say, be called before that new call? In my case, costructor is called, and only then destructor called for freshly initialized object.

Comment: And when you comment or does not write initialisztion part (after ':' and before '{' ) the defauld constructo is used. and when you reassign in constructor body - destructor is called anyway.

Comment: 1. temporary object created with constructor. 2. destructor of object where to assign is called. 3. object where to assign copy constructor is caled 4. temporary object is destroyed by destructor.

Comment: 1. In this case: what is "temporary object" and "object where to assign"?
2. So that means that I am calling copy-constructor?
3. Can you please write the code so I would understant better? Thank you.

Comment: users_items = menu_item_touch_button::menu_item_touch_button(menu_item_common::BACKG_LONG); users_items - object where to assign, result of menu_item_touch_button - return temporary object (or it return ref, what is signature of it?) Possible you need to simplify design to rule of 0 to avoid problems, read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29

Answer (score 2):

You can initialize an array:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

struct Element
{
    Element() : _value(0) {}
    Element(int value) : _value(value) {}
    int _value;
};

class Container
{
    std::array<Element, 10> _elements; // Element _elements[10]; works too
public:
    Container()
        : _elements({ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 })
    {}

    int at(size_t index) { return _elements[index]._value; }
};

int main()
{
    Container cont;
    std::cout << cont.at(5) << std::endl;
}
```

Prints `6` as expected.

Comment: [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) is an *aggregate* type, just like normal arrays, so it doesn't use `std::initializer_list`. A normal array could be initialized just the same way.

Comment: I need something simple and default...
I do not understant why this doeasn't work
Code does not format... :( ) user_menu_view::user_menu_view() : button_clicked_callback(this, &user_menu_view::button_clicked), on_touch_button_item_selected(this, &user_menu_view::touch_button_item_selected) { users_items[0] = menu_item_touch_button::menu_item_touch_button(menu_item_common::BACKG_LONG); users_items[0].set_back_color((uint16_t)0x1951); meniu_list.add(users_items[0]); }

Comment: @JoachimPileborg of course, I started with an `std::vector` then realised OP doesn't need dynamic sizing. I updated my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass() {
        for(int i=0;i<10;++i)
            items[i]=Member(i);
    }
    ~MyClass();

private:
    Member items[10];
}
```

UPD: You need to implement carefully destructor and copy-constructor of your Member class. It must not be valid and does not crash your logic when copyed and replaced over by value. the copy constructor is like this:

```
Member( const Member& m ) {
 dummy = m.dummy;
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was trying. But it doesn't work.
Imediatelly after constructor routine destructopr is called. I have done debuging.

(Code does not format... :( )
user_menu_view::user_menu_view() :
    button_clicked_callback(this, &user_menu_view::button_clicked),
    on_touch_button_item_selected(this, &user_menu_view::touch_button_item_selected)
{
    users_items[0] = menu_item_touch_button::menu_item_touch_button(menu_item_common::BACKG_LONG);
    users_items[0].set_back_color((uint16_t)0x1951);
    meniu_list.add(users_items[0]);
}

Comment: see upd, possible problem occur at copy operation of complicated class

Comment: see one more upd, where introduced C++11 compatible solution

Comment: @KarolisMilieška you should post such things as an update to your question, or a brand new question

Comment: Whad do you mean? I have write mark "UPD". And I does not do post "question". I am move upd in to new created answer. Is this all right?

Answer (score 0):

The array content will be initialized by the default constructor of `Member`. To fill it with individual content you'll need some additional code to replace the default-constructed values, usually in the constructor of the class of which the array is a member.

You should also consider using `std::vector` or `std::list`, whatever fits your use case better, instead of C arrays if possible.

Answer (score 0):

If your compiler is support C++11 you can simple do like this:
(possible it solve the problem with copying objects of complicated classes)

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass() : items({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}) {};
    ~MyClass();

private:
    Member items[10];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are a bit confused about what happens when, exactly, during the construction of an object.

```
class MyClass
{
    private:
        Member_x x;
        Member_y y;
    public:
        MyClass( int i ) : x( i );
        {
            y = Member_y( 42 );
        }
};
```

By the time the copy constructor reaches that opening `{`, **all member variables not explicitly constructed in the member initializer list have been default-constructed**.

That is a requirement so all member variables are in a well-defined state, so you can actually *access* them in the constructor body.

This means that calling the copy constructor in my example would:

- call `Member_x( i )`;
- *implicitly* call `Member_y()`;
- call `~Member_y()` (because the object referred to by `y` goes out-of-scope as the new value gets assigned);
- call `Member_y( 42 )`.

That is  obviously not what you want -- you want to avoid that implicit constructor / destructor call. The only way to do so is to move the initialization into the member initializer list.

> why this work

Because it's calling the copy constructor in the member initializer list (as with `Member_x` in my example)

> And this doesn't:

Because it's calling the default constructor, then assigns a new value in the constructor body (as with `Member_y` in my example). It "works" as well, it just does additional and unnecessary work.

---

So, you **must** initialize your `Member items[]` in the member initializer list if you want to

1. use the `Member` copy constructor,
2. don't want to have temporary `Member` objects default-constructed / destroyed.

The second answer by user oklas does this with a plain old array, YSC does it with `std::array`, and it could be done the same way with `std::vector`. The important thing is that the initialization is done in the initializer list, not the `MyClass` constructor body.

Both showcased solutions are as "simple" and "default" as it gets.